# ZF2 Hostname Routing with found value as default

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I want to create a whitelabel-ready site and want to use the hostname routing for that. 
I created a parent-route for all other routes, which just stores the found hostname in a variable called "whitelabel"

The created array:

```
<?php
$route = array(
'type' => 'Hostname',
    'options' => array(
    'route' => ':whitelabel',
    'defaults' => array(
        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
        'controller' => 'Index',
        'action' => 'index',
    ),
),
);
?>
```

Right now, whenever I call the url helper in views it is unable to find a value for 'whitelabel'. How can I store the found value as default value for the url helper?

Comment: The url helper produces relative paths. Why do you need the domain name, when the paths are always relative to the current host?

Comment: I get the following error when calling the url helper with no value for "whitelabel":
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Missing parameter "whitelabel"' in

Comment: You'd normally configure the route in a config file, and it would have a name (array key) encapsulating the route definition, you use that to point the url helper in the right direction. For example, in the skeleton app, the route `/` is actually referenced by calling `$this->url('home')`. Maybe I'm missing how the hostname route works here, it's not one I've had call to use, but the first thing that struck me was the seemingly unnecessary need for any kind of host to be passed to the url helper with its relative paths

Comment: As far as I am right, I need to configure the route I called "register" as a child route of the hostname route, since I want to check for the hostname as well. When I call 
    $this->url('hostname/register') 
now I either get this error, or - if I set a default value for whitelabel - it generates an url http://defaultvalue/relative/path/with/route

Problem: I'd loose the whitelabel version if I set the default value to the provider of the plattform, and it would be just a lot of more work to always reassign the whitelabel value in url helper calls

Comment: Had a quick play around using your specs, adding `whitelabel` as a param, eg `$this->url('hostname/register', array('whitelabel' => 'some.domain.tld')); produces as a url `some.domain.tld/register` however, the resulting link is a 404, so I still don't think I'm grepping how it's meant to work :-?

Comment: Hey, the fourth parameter of the url helper was what I were looking for. Thank you for your help anyways, I guess it gave a great insight into those two pieces of the zf2